# How to make termux-clipboard-set/get in chroot?

Tags: termux, copy-paste

`termux-clipboard-set` and `termux-clipboard-get` are accessible on termux and proot. But they are not available on chroot. Probably because some library is missing.

Any way to make it work? Or what library do I need to copy over?